# Is there any way to detect image transparent boundaries with Imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Let's take a sample image shown below. I've to get top-left X0,Y0 & bottom-right X1,Y1 of transparent area.

[image: Image with transparency]

One way is to convert image into txt file & then parse a file to detect these points.

```
convert image.png txt:- | grep "#000000" > image_transp.txt
```

Could it be done more simplier with Imagick?

Comment: You could [export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.exportimagepixels.php) just the Alpha channel and loop through them, keeping track of the upper-left and lower-right most values.

Comment: @Gavin thank you for response. It's pretty straight-forward way to iterate over pixel. I thought there were more convenient way to achieve this.

Comment: Without IM: use a bitmap-to-vector utility (potrace or else) and check the anchors of the output vector.